How does the Google Dialer stream call recording info audio to the other side?
As soon as a call recording is started in the Phone by Google app, an audio is played which the receiver can listen even if microphone usage is closed. How to implement this in an Android app ? I only want to know how to implement the audio streaming part.
I have seen a lot of related questions but either they do not completely answer it or are not answered altogether.
